# A Problem To Manage SqlExceptions in C#

Tags: c#, sqlexception

I want to write a class to manage sqlexceptions. This class will display a message in my language for each sqlexception.

**But how can i gather all error codes or part of error codes that occur more than others?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the information with the SQL Query `SELECT * FROM sysmessages`

More info and a list of error codes here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917589.aspx

Comment: **Sorry bro,the site you linked it has filtered in my country**